# error: Overflow uinit uint256

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens

I have a token with overflow function can you help me use it[image]

Now i can't use this function, please anyone can help me???
I will pay 2 BNB salary

Comment: I can still use this function if the amout is set to 0 but 1 or greater is not

Comment: what are you trying to do? it's not the done thing to have so much code on one line (in style guide terms), and we can even see all of it ... but what are you trying to do here?
does the math of all that code at any point go over `type(uint256).max`? `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935`

Comment: @QuyTrong Please, include the source code as text. It is really hard to test and try. My guess is that you are missing a few parenthesis and you really need to simplify the division there are too many multiplication and division by a power of 10.

Comment: here is my code https://bscscan.com/address/0x3ce00515409926db5a1765b8d58f8fe5261d7b46#code   i was deploy this contract and i dont know how to use this function if "amout" > 0

Comment: @Ismael I guess there are too many zeros so the code can't run, but I created the contract so now I can't edit the code

Comment: Why do you have so many `(10 ** _decimals)`? It doesn't make sense have that many. Also `A * B / C * D` in solidity is computed as `((A * B) / C) * D`.

Comment: @Ismael it was my fault, and now i don't know what to do